# Flot donut chart disappears when labels are shown

Tags: jquery, flot, pie-chart, donut-chart

I have a created a simple donut chart with flot. However, if I use the default settings the labels are not displayed (even if I specify "show: true"). Only when I hide the legend, the labels are displayed but then the chart itself disappears. Am I missing something or is this a bug in the flot library?

This is my code:

```
var data = [
  {label: "A", data: 373, color: "red"},
  {label: "B", data: 84, color: "blue"},
  {label: "C", data: 73, color: "green"}    
];

$.plot("#chart", data, {
  series: {
    pie: {
      innerRadius: 0.75,
      show: true,
    }
  },
  label: {
    show: true,
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  }
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ds0zyc2s/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the pie chart plugin code, the legend visibility controls the label visibility, which in turn controls the radius of the chart if `pie.radius` is set to `auto` (which is the default value if it has't been explicitly set - applicable code below).

You happened to pick `.75` as the `innerRadius` of the chart, which is what the plugin sets as the radius in this situation. When `radius` and `innerRadius` are equal, the disappearing phenomenon you're describing occurs.

```
// set labels.show
if (options.series.pie.label.show == "auto") {
    if (options.legend.show) {
        options.series.pie.label.show = false;
    } else {
        options.series.pie.label.show = true;
    }
}

// set radius
if (options.series.pie.radius == "auto") {
    if (options.series.pie.label.show) {
        options.series.pie.radius = 3/4;
    } else {
        options.series.pie.radius = 1;
    }
}
```

Why was the plugin written this way? I'm not sure - but you can fix it by setting your `innerRadius` to something other than `.75` when you've turned off the legend, or specifying both the `innerRadius` and `radius` properties:

```js
$(function() {
  var data = [{
    label: "A",
    data: 373,
    color: "red"
  }, {
    label: "B",
    data: 84,
    color: "blue"
  }, {
    label: "C",
    data: 73,
    color: "green"
  }];

  $.plot("#chart", data, {
    series: {
      pie: {
        innerRadius: 0.5,
        radius: .75,
        show: true,
      }
    },
    label: {
      show: true,
    },
    legend: {
      show: false
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>
```